# UIScrollView - Unable to scroll to the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a view which is about three times the size of the UIScrollView.  I've configured the scroll view like this:

```
_scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
_scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[_scrollView addSubview:mapView];
_scrollView.contentSize = mapFrame.size;
_scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

I've also assigned a feasible zoom level inspired by [Matt Galloway's  tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518):

```
-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = _scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // Calculate the content size for the scroll view
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
}
```

My problem is that I can't reach the bottom of the scroll view's subview. It always bounces back about 1/6 of the subview's height. Do you have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

An image illustrating the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjpaw.jpg. You can see that the bottom square is cut off by the scrolling issue.

**Edit**

I resolved the issue by creating the UIScrollView programmatically. It was previously defined in the storyboard. I'm still rather curious what I was potentially doing wrong–perhaps the proportions were different? Checking this out now.

**Edit #2**

No, the sizes were the same. This will remain a mystery to me :)

Comment: Is your scrollView's contentSize correct?

Comment: I had the same issue, my problem was a wrong content size

Comment: `mapFrame` is the frame passed as the `frame` argument to mapView's `initWithFrame`, so it ought to be correct, unless there is something I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by creating the UIScrollView programmatically. It was previously defined in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This will be caused by iOS 7's new settings in the `Attributes inspector` for the `View Controller`.
`Adjust Scroll View Insets`, `Under Top Bars`, `Under Bottom Bars` & `Under Opaque Bars`.
These are used when you want the scrollview to scroll underneath a navigation bar or tab bar.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to try this! :) I added the UIScrollView to the storyboard again and I made sure to  untick these boxes, but it still doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.